# Еlectric network

Tags: probability

We have the  part of the circuit (see Fig.). Each resistor with probability 1/2 may be intact (conductive) or damaged (not conductive). What is the probability that the current will pass through this part of the circuit?

[image]

Comment: Well, that's a lot of resistor

Comment: Are the resistors independent?

Comment: yes, they are independed

Comment: Do you have more context for the problem?

Comment: I think this is essentially a math question, but I'm a little confused on the meaning.  Are you saying the resistors act just like on/off switches?

Comment: We have enough to solve it by using simple theorems of elementary probality

Comment: *Are you saying the resistors act just like on/off switches?*  Yes - it does work  or not. Two states only.

Comment: This is a graph connectivity problem, where the presence of not of edges is probabilistic.

Comment: Hence `2^(10^2+9^2)` states for the network.

Comment: yes.. $2^{10^2+9^2}$ will be in the denominator of an answer.  what  be  in the numerator?

Comment: Any ideas with this? I'm surprised that it can be solved using elementary stuff? Seems like a moderately complicated graph theory problem to me?

Comment: Idea. Let $n=10$ be the dimension of the problem, and let $S_n$  denotes the number of states when the current will pass through  the circuit. I hope that there is a simple reccurence relation for $S_n$.

Comment: The ansver is $\frac{1}{2}$  but I can't  prove it.

Comment: Use induction! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Consider the dual graph with the additional top and bottom vertices which corresponding to upper and lower part of the plane. Suppose that the vertices of the dual graph is adjacent iff the corresponding faces share edge which is not conductive. Then the top and bottom vertices are electrically connected iff the current cannot flow.
Because of the symmetry, we have the same probability for the event and the complement. Therefore the probability is 1/2.